# Eclipse Project Settings Not Transferring to New Project

Tags: c, eclipse, project-settings

I have the source from an Eclipse project, and I need to import all of the build settings as well as the source into a new project so I can make some changes. The trouble is, when I go to build the project, Eclipse is calling the internal builder and NOT calling the Makefile from the previous project (which I have imported). The makefile contains some values in #define statements that need to be passed in on the command line.

When I go to change these options in Eclipse (by right clicking on the project and going down to "Properties" and then examining the "C/C++ Build" tab) they are grayed out!

If someone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called ".settings" under your project, copy this (and everything under it) to your new project, this is where all of the settings are stored. To see the folder, you may need to use the view menu (upside down triangle) in the Package or Project Explorer and remove the filter on the ".resources". For Package Explorer select the "Filters", in Project Explorer use "Customize View"